# Pagination with Flutter, Ferry, Graphql?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, pagination, ferry

I have graphql hooked up, and the collection in question has about 2000 documents. What I want to do is simply load in 25 at a time. If I perform the query to fetch the full list it takes 5-10 seconds, so what I need is for it to only ask for 25 at a time.
I have it working so it will load up X amount of documents and display them in a list. What I cannot figure out is how to get pagination working. Ive read the docs 100 times, but I cannot make sense of it. Here is the pagination doc for ferry https://ferrygraphql.com/docs/pagination

I am fairly new to flutter and dart so any help here would be appriecited. Thank you.

This is my code. Currently this just displays the first 25 documents and nothing else.

```
class DisplayPartnerOrganistions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DisplayPartnerOrganistionsState createState() =>
      _DisplayPartnerOrganistionsState();
}

class _DisplayPartnerOrganistionsState
    extends State<DisplayPartnerOrganistions> {
  var offset = 0;
  final client = GetIt.I<Client>();
  late GFetchPartnerOrganisationsReq fetchPartnerOrganisationsReq;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPartnerOrganisationsReq = GFetchPartnerOrganisationsReq(
      (b) => b
        ..vars.offset = offset
        ..vars.limit = 25,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(partners) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: (context, item) {
          return _buildRow(partners[item]);
        });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(partnerOrganisation) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(partnerOrganisation.toString()),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Partner Organisations'),
      ),
      body: Operation<GFetchPartnerOrganisationsData,
              GFetchPartnerOrganisationsVars>(
          client: client,
          operationRequest: fetchPartnerOrganisationsReq,
          builder: (context, response, error) {
            if (response!.loading) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            final partners = response.data?.partnerOrganizations;
            return _buildList(partners);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

I been trying different things for about 12 hours but nothing is making any sense. Am I using the wrong widgets or something?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `requestId` so ferry considers the different request for the different pages the same one:

```dart
final fetchPartnerOrganisationsReq = GFetchPartnerOrganisationsReq((req) =>
  req
    ..requestId = 'myRequestId'
    ..vars.offset = 0
    ..vars.limit = 25,
);
```

If you don't do this, ferry creates an id from your request type and the variables of the request, which will be different for the different pages (`offset` won't be the same).

Then when you need to load more data, you can rebuild the request with different variables (`offset`). Rebuilding it will allow you to keep the same `requestId` you specified in the first place.

```dart
final newRequest = fetchPartnerOrganisationsReq.rebuild((request) =>
  // `requestId` is still `'myRequestId'`
  request..vars.offset = fetchPartnerOrganisationsReq.vars.offset + 25 // <- You update the offset here
  request..updateResult = (previous, result) {
    // This tells ferry what to do when you get the result from the new query.
    // Since it is using the same id as the initial one (with `offset = 0`), by default it will override the result.
    // Here we can tell ferry how to keep both.
    // `previous` is what you already received in the previous query (the previous page).
    // `result` is the new page you get.
    if (previous == null) return result; // If we didn't have a previous page yet, we just use what we got with the new query.
    return previous!.rebuild((previous) =>
      previous.partnerOrganizations.addAll(result!.partnerOrganizations), // We concatenate the lists of the previous pages and the new one.
    );
  },
);
```

---

When do you create a new request ?

It can be when you reach the end of a list. You can know that by using a `ScrollController()` with a listener. You can know you reached the end of the list with `_scrollController.position.extentAfter == 0`).

Comment: how should the `newRequest` be used after it's created here? Does it need to be added to the Operation Widget somehow? Without doing anything, I can't get the `updateResult` method to execute